# How to run unit tests with karma in an angularjs upgrade (1 -> 2) project?

Tags: angularjs, angular, karma-jasmine

I'm working through the [angular-phonecat update tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#phonecat-upgrade-tutorial). I try to get unit-tests running at the step where the `Phone`-service is converted to `angular2`. The application itself is running but not the tests. The tests that are only in touch with `angluarjs` are running and also the tests that are only in touch with `angular2`. But the mixed ones doesn't run. The `Phone`-service is not injected:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: PhoneProvider <- Phone
[1]     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/unpr?p0=PhoneProvider%20%3C-%20Phone
```

I put the code on a bitbucket [repo](https://bitbucket.org/michel73/angular-phonecat-upgrade).

I guess the problem is something with the `UpgradeModule`. I tried a lot and got really confused. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Or does anybody knows a running upgrade example on a public repository with mixed  `angularjs`and `angular` in its tests?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that you are still need it, but probably it would be useful for someone

```
import "angular-mocks/ngMock";
import * as angular from "angular";

import {inject, TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {Inject, Injectable, FactoryProvider} from "@angular/core";
import {AngularJSService} from "angularjs/angularjs.service" // angularjs service which is upgraded and injected in ExampleService angular service

// upgrading angular js service to make it possible to inject into angular services/components
const UpgradedProvider: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: AngularJSService,
  useFactory: ($injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService) => {$injector.get('AngularJSService')},
  deps: ['$injector']
};

// this is angular service which has upgraded angularjs service in dependency
@Injectable()
class ExampleService {
  public name: string = 'Example Service';

  constructor(angularJSService: AngularJSService) {
    // injecting angular js service
  }
}

describe('Angular Example Test Suite ', () => {
  let $injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // init angular js module for test and define upgraded angular js service in this module
    angular.module('ExampleTest', []).service('AngularJSService', AngularJSService);
  });

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ExampleTest'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject((_$injector_: ng.auto.IInjectorService) => {
    $injector = _$injector_;
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: '$injector',
          useFactory: () => $injector,
          deps: []
        },
        UpgradedProvider,
        ExampleService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should inject ExampleService', inject([ExampleService], (exampleService: ExampleService) => {
    chai.assert.isDefined(exampleService);
  }));
});
```